# store every letter of a string in variable with a loop

Tags: r

Suppose I do something like the following:

```
x <- 'zeal'
t <- strsplit(x, '')
g <- unlist(t)
g
[1]"z" "e" "a" "l" 
r <- letters[(which(g[1] == letters))]
r
[1]"z"
```

My end goal for this is to have something where I can say "find the element in `some variable` which matches `something` so for example, if I had

```
e <- 'bacon'
e <- strsplit(e, '')
e <- unlist(e)
e
[1]"b" "a" "c" "o" "n"
```

then "find the element in `e` which matches "b"". And then apply that over until all elements in `e` are matched

Comment: What is the desired output here? Can you describe what you are trying to do in words?

Comment: Hi, I've edited it with some further explanation, hopefully that helps.

Comment: You're still missing half your input and your desired output. "find the element in `e` which matches "b"", I see `e`, but where does "b" come from? are you doing all `letters`?

Comment: Something like `sapply(letters, FUN = function(x) which(grepl(x, e)))`?

Comment: I agree with Gregor, you are still missing importing information in your question. But maybe you are looking for `match()`? Maybe check out [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe provide some sample function that you want to run on all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing the `sum` does anything because each `g` element will only match once.  Here you can you use an `apply` function instead of explicit loop as is standard in R.  The variable `i` is like `g[i]` as you have it written.

```
sapply(g, function(i) letters[which(i == letters)])
```

Comment: oh ok, i've remvoed the `sum`,